# Open video with (my app) on iOS

Tags: ios, plist

I'm creating an iOS app that essentially uploads video files to a cloud server, among other things. To make it more useable, I'd like to implement an Open with/Share with my app button. When you open the camera roll on iOS devices, select a video and click the Share button, a list of compatible apps shows up. I'd like to place my app in this list.

I did some research on the Internet, and found I had to add the file type to my plist file, so I added:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.video</string>
            <string>public.movie</string>
            <string>public.mpeg-4</string>
            <string>com.apple.m4v-video</string>
            <string>com.apple.quicktime-movie</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>Moment</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

My app isn't showing up, however. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

`LSItemContentTypes` is for the document controller. Since you're wanting to do this from the camera roll, you may be looking to create a [Share Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html).